# Hypriot ARM32v7 Ubuntu apt-get update Exit Code: 132

Tags: docker-compose, hypriot

I'm attempting to docker-compose with one service using arm32v7/ubuntu:latest.

It runs into the first RUN apt-get update  and then fails with

`ERROR: compose.cli.main.main: Service 'app2' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y git' returned a non-zero code: 132`

Dockerfile:

```
FROM arm32v7/ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update 

RUN apt-get install -y git
RUN apt-get install -y python
RUN apt-get install -y python-dev
RUN apt-get install -y python-setuptools
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip
RUN apt-get install -y nginx 
RUN apt-get install -y postgresql 
RUN apt-get install -y postgresql-contrib 
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor
RUN apt-get install -y sqlite3

RUN pip install -U pip setuptools
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# install uwsgi now because it takes a little while

RUN pip install uwsgi

# setup all the configfiles

RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY nginx-app.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
COPY supervisor-app.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/



# COPY requirements.txt and RUN pip install BEFORE adding the rest of your code, this will cause Docker's caching mechanism
# to prevent re-installinig (all your) dependencies when you made a change a line or two in your app.


RUN mkdir  -p /home/docker/code/app

COPY requirements.txt /home/docker/code/app/
RUN pip install -r /home/docker/code/app/requirements.txt



# add (the rest of) our code
COPY . /home/docker/code/


EXPOSE 80
CMD ["supervisord", "-n"]
```

There are several things I'm not sure about, not the least of which is using ARM32V6 vs V7 on my RPI.

RPI Details:

```
$ uname -a 
Linux black-pearl 4.4.50-hypriotos+ #2 PREEMPT Sun Mar 19 14:44:01 UTC
2017 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Docker info

```
    $ docker info
    Containers: 4
    Running: 0
    Paused: 0
    Stopped: 4
    Images: 9
    Server Version: 17.03.0-ce
    Storage Driver: overlay2
     Backing Filesystem: extfs
     Supports d_type: true
     Native Overlay Diff: true
    Logging Driver: json-file
    Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
    Plugins:
     Volume: local
     Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
    Swarm: inactive
    Runtimes: runc
    Default Runtime: runc
    Init Binary: docker-init
    containerd version: 977c511eda0925a723debdc94d09459af49d082a
    runc version: a01dafd48bc1c7cc12bdb01206f9fea7dd6feb70
    init version: 949e6fa
    Kernel Version: 4.4.50-hypriotos+
    Operating System: Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)
    OSType: linux
    Architecture: armv6l
    CPUs: 1
    Total Memory: 370.7 MiB
    Name: black-pearl
    ID: TJDD:PP7C:44SF:KGBG:UOOF:4PA7:SACD:I4DY:LJSU:5HBO:UFJQ:F2FX
    Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
    Debug Mode (client): false
    Debug Mode (server): false
    Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
    Experimental: false
```

Answer (score 0):

ARMv7 should be fine with RPi2 or 3.
Try to run docker build --no-cache . with your Dockerfile to see if it still happens. Maybe you have an outdated cached layer with the "apt-get install" command that must be built again with current data.
Otherwise try FROM resin/rpi-raspbian which should be a better fit for RPi.

Comment: I have the same problem. Running with --no-cache did not help.